# Concatenating records (names) in a row to create an email address

Tags: sql-server

I am using SQL server studio management. Below is the issue I am encountering.

Table name: Citizen

```
Firstname       Lastname        Email

John             Smith      jsoi@yahoo.com

Andrew           Evans     evanda@gmail.com
```

I would like to change the email addresses for both records to adopt the format

john.smith@ipno.gov.uk
 Andrew.evans@ipno.gov.uk

INTENDED:

```
Firstname       Lastname        Email

John             Smith      John.Smith@ipno.gov.uk

Andrew           Evans     Andrew.Evans@ipno.gov.uk
```

So it will be a concatenation of firstname and lastname with a dot in between them and addition of @ipno.gov.uk

I will really appreciate your help or guidance on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are going to update the whole table. Try this simple method,

Lower()-> To convert uppercase characters if any to lower case.

```
UPDATE Citizens
SET Email = Lower(FirstName) + '.' + Lower(LastName) + '@ipno.gov.uk'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE Citizens SET Email = LOWER(FirstName) + '.' + LOWER(LastName) + '@ipno.gov.uk' WHERE FirstName IN ('John', 'Andrew') AND LastName IN ('Smith', 'Evans')
```

Comment: Some explanation might be helpful - code-only answers are discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server 2012+, you can use use [`CONCAT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231515.aspx)

```
CONCAT(LOWER(FirstName), '.', LOWER(LastName), '@ipno.gov.uk')
```

Sample execution with the given data:

```
DECLARE @Citizens TABLE (FirstName VARCHAR (100), LastName VARCHAR (100), Email VARCHAR (100));

INSERT INTO @Citizens (FirstName, LastName, Email) VALUES 
('John', 'Smith', 'jsoi@yahoo.com'),
('Andrew', 'Evans', 'evanda@gmail.com');

-- Only to update the two records need to add the WHERE clause
-- If you want to update for all the entries in the table remove the WHERE clause

UPDATE @Citizens SET Email = CONCAT(LOWER(FirstName), '.', LOWER(LastName), '@ipno.gov.uk')
FROM @Citizens
WHERE FirstName = 'John' AND LastName = 'Smith'

UPDATE @Citizens SET Email = CONCAT(LOWER(FirstName), '.', LOWER(LastName), '@ipno.gov.uk')
FROM @Citizens
WHERE FirstName = 'Andrew' AND LastName = 'Evans'
```

Comment: thanks for this....why did you use the DECLARE command..I am new to SQL, not sure I understand the use of it